# The chrome around my windows appears to have disappeared. Any ideas why?

Tags: unity, window-manager

When my windows are not maximised the title bar disappears and the only way to get hold of the application pane is to Alt + Click and Drag.

I am running Natty with Unity and I have not restarted the machine since experiencing the problem. This is because I have a long running process executing on my machine.

Is there an option I might have accidentally enabled? Or does it sound like some kind of process crash? How can I rectify it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a compiz problem. Without using ccsm you can enter hit `Alt + F2` and enter the command `compiz --replace`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having this problem as well (In Unity and in Classic). A temporary workaround is to start compizconfig-settings-manager (CCSM), then un-select and re-select window decorations. This will restore your titles, etc. It seem to be a problem with the newer compiz (OpenGL perhaps).

Comment: I cannot find the `compiz-settings-manager` anywhere. How do I get it running? Running `compiz-decorator &` in the console brings the toolbars back so it looks like this is definitely the problem.

Comment: The module is called compizconfig-settings manager. Thanks for the tip with compiz-decorator, I believe that's actually what the settings manager runs, and the workaround is more direct.

Answer (score 0):

An immediate solution to the problem is to:

1. Hit Ctrl + Alt + T to open a new terminal
2. Then type `compiz-decorator &` and hit enter
3. You can now close the terminal

The ampersand (`&`) after the command causes it to run the background so it will still run even after closing the terminal window.